# 3 Tables = 1 List

Tags: php, sql

I have three tables (individuals, groups & recordlabels) and want use the information between them to make a listing of people within the record label. Example: It should find the individuals and groups with the companyID of # and list them. How do I create this correctly without duplicates of the results?

```
// Connect to database
include "mysqli_connect.php";

// Set variables
$url_num = $_GET['company_id'];
$company_num = "";
$company_members = "";
$company_members2 = "";

//Check for artist id pagination
if(is_numeric($url_num)){
    $company = intval($url_num);
}else{
    $company = 1;
}

// Construct our join query
$sqli = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM recordlabels
INNER JOIN individuals ON individuals.companyID=recordlabels.companyID
INNER JOIN groups ON groups.companyID=recordlabels.companyID
WHERE recordlabels.companyID = '{$company}'";

// Create results
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sqli);

//Check for albums
$totalmembers = mysqli_num_rows($result);

// Checking if query is successful
if($result){

// Print out the contents of each row into a table 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)){

// Assign value of column if not empty, otherwise "DamJuNoImage" (Thanks to Jonathan Sampson from Stack Overflow)
    $companyen = empty( $row["companyen"] ) 
        ? "Unknown" 
        : $row["companyen"];
    $companyko = empty( $row["companyko"] ) 
        ? "Unknown" 
        : $row["companyko"];
    $companyType = empty( $row["companyType"] ) 
        ? "Unknown" 
        : $row["companyType"];
    $founded = empty( $row["established"] ) 
        ? "Unknown" 
        : $row["established"];
    $founder = empty( $row["companyFounder"] ) 
        ? "Unknown" 
        : $row["companyFounder"];
    $information = empty( $row["information"] ) 
        ? "Unknown" 
        : $row["information"];
    $location = empty( $row["companyLocation"] ) 
        ? "Unknown" 
        : $row["companyLocation"];
    $homepage = empty( $row["companyPage"] ) 
        ? "#" 
        : $row["homepage"];
    $solopic = empty( $row["solopic"] ) 
        ? "DamjuNoImage" 
        : $row["solopic"];
    $soloen = empty( $row["soloen"] )
        ? "Unknown"
        : $row["soloen"];
    $solokn = empty( $row["solokn"] )
        ? "Unknown"
        : $row["solokn"];
    $grouppic = empty( $row["grouppic"] ) 
        ? "DamjuNoImage" 
        : $row["grouppic"];
    $groupen = empty( $row["groupen"] )
        ? "Unknown"
        : $row["groupen"];
    $groupkn = empty( $row["groupkn"] )
        ? "Unknown"
        : $row["groupkn"];
    $company_members .= '<li><a href="#">
      <div class="image"><img src="pathhere/' . $solopic . '"></div>
      <p class="datatitle2">' . $soloen . '</p>
      <p class="data-info2">' . $solokn . '</p>
      </a></li>';
    $company_members2 .= '<li><a href="#">
      <div class="image"><img src="pathhere' . $grouppic . '"></div>
      <p class="datatitle2">' . $groupen . '</p>
      <p class="data-info2">' . $groupkn . '</p>
      </a></li>';
    $listofmembers = $company_members . $company_members2; 
} // End of while statement
}else{
    echo "No people under $companyen";
} // End of If statement
```

To give a (hopefully) better visual.

- Bob (individuals)
- Lisa (individuals)
- Mania (groups)

My testing before seeking help gave this result:

- Bob (individuals)
- Lisa (individuals)
- Mania (groups)
- Mania (groups)

That was because I put the output of individuals and groups in their own separate value. Then I  echoed `$var1 . $var2` which I felt would go wrong.

UPDATE: If nobody can figure it out, I'll just redo my database and tables. Thank you all you tried to help.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT <real-field-list> FROM ...` instead of `SELECT * FROM ...`

Comment: @EugenRieck is right, but you really should ASK A QUESTION in order for us to know what you want.

Comment: lol oops I got sucked into explaining and forgot to add the question

Comment: @ghoti Wouldn't it be just php since I'm trying to loop from individuals and groups table?

Comment: I haven't seen any PHP that looks like it might be looping through a result set; the only code in your question that actually affects functionality (and result generation) is the SQL.  The solution to your problem is almost certainly to construct your query correctly, as Eugen suggested.  So no, I think the SQL tag is what you need, even if you don't know it.  :)

Comment: Alright. I tried his way but I got errors.

Comment: Is there any correlation between `group` and `individual`, or is the only link the `company` record (which I'm assuming is something like the managing company)?  Also, from the little you've posted, you may be open to SQL Injection - you need to force the cast to a numeric type, at minimum (and should probably be using prepared statements regardless).  Also, best practice dictates using a list of specific fields in a `SELECT` statement, for a number of reasons (although this won't solve your problem).

Comment: @X-Zero the companyID is numeric and I check for it too. individual has a groupID link.

Comment: @ghoti I have a loop (while) but I didn't put it in there since it wasn't part of the problem.

Comment: If you want help with PHP code, include PHP code in your question.  If you do further research that will help folks here understand what's going on, like a revised SQL query and the error you got as a result, click the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11022961/edit) link under your question and provide an update.

Comment: I'll post the whole php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is most likely coming from your SQL code.  Specifically, you appear to have some denormalization, with `companyId` in both `individual` *and* `group`, and `individual` having a `groupId` foreign key.

Given this relationship, you most probably want to write your statement along these lines:

```
SELECT companyEn, companyKo, companyType, established, companyFounder, 
       information, companyLocation, companyPage,
       soloPic, soloEn, soloKn, 
       groupPic, groupEn, groupKn
FROM recordLabels
JOIN groups 
ON groups.companyId = recordLabels.companyId
JOIN individuals
ON individuals.groupId = groups.groupId
WHERE recordLabels.companyId = $company
```

Other minor notes:
From what I've heard, best practice usually gives tables *singular* names, not plural ones.
What's up with the `....En` and `...Ko` columns?  It seems to me like you may be doing some internationalization (English and Korean?) - if so, you're going to want to extract those columns out of the original tables, and start translation tables.  This will aid you **greatly** if you need to add support for additional languages later.

---

## EDIT:

Although there's multiple ways to handle translation tables, you probably want one translation table per table that needs translated data.  You'll also probably want a standard language table for reference:

```
language
============
id  -- autoincrement - or possibly just use code
code  -- ISO 3-letter code, unique
shortCode  -- ISO 2-letter code, unique (I think?)
name  -- ISO standard name
```

Taking `recordLabel` as an example:

1) Create your translated table, with all columns that will need to be translated:

```
recordLabelTranslation
=====================
companyId  -- fk to recordLabel.companyId, or whatever the primary key of that table is
languageId  -- fk to language.id
company  -- whatever 'companyEn' and 'companyKo' was (company name?  why translate?)
```

2) Remove all columns that were translated (`companyEn`, `companyKo`)

3) (optional) code up a view so you have an easy reference.  There are two flavours:

-> simple join for language

```
CREATE VIEW Record_Label_Language as 
SELECT recordLabel.companyId, recordLabel.information, -- all current columns...
       recordLabelTranslation.languageId, recordLabelTranslation.company
FROM recordLabel
JOIN recordLabelTranslation
ON recordLabelTranslation.companyId = recordLabel.companyid
```

-> join for language, with default to english (or some other language)

```
CREATE VIEW Record_Label_Language_Default as 
SELECT recordLabel.companyId, recordLabel.information, -- all current columns...
       COALESCE(recordLabelTranslation.languageId, language.languageId),
       COALESCE(recordLabelTranslation.company, dflt.company)
FROM recordLabel
JOIN recordLabelTranslation as dflt
ON dflt.companyId = recordLabel.companyid
AND dflt.languageId = [englishLanguageId]
CROSS JOIN language
LEFT JOIN recordLabelTranslation
ON recordLabelTranslation.companyId = recordLabel.companyId
AND recordLabelTranslation.languageId = language.id
```

Comment: Correct. En is English and Ko is Korean. Translation tables? So have one table in English and the other in Korean?

Comment: I'll just try to find a way to combine my individuals and groups table together as one table. And I'll follow your advice. Thanks.

Comment: ... Why?  Is an individual a group (I kinda doubt it)?  Start with a normalized design, only denormalize for _performance_ reasons (and maybe not even then, sorta).

Comment: Individual was for producers, solo artists..etc. Group was for individuals in groups.

Comment: I was trying to figure this site out: http://music.daum.net/artist/main?artistDetailId=243003 since both individuals and groups share the `?artistDetailID=#` part.

Comment: That's probably a different backend altogether, but one option is that it's really equivalent to the `groupId`, and you can have groups of just one person.